# How to robustly seek in a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, find

My DataFrame has an indexed column with type of `np.datetime64`, and no duplicated key values, and the data has been sorted before `read_csv`.

Now I need to seek in it with a `np.datetime64` value.
I want to find the first row whose index value is greater or equal the seeking key.

I'm a beginner user of pandas, I don't known how to find a correct method to get my goal.

1. `DataFrame.loc()` method returns a reference to a row, while I need a **primary integer location number** that can be passed into
   `DataFrame.iloc()` (just likes the indics of an array in C language),
   so as to I can store it for later using, to prevent from seeking it
   with same key value repeatedly (my df is huge);
2. `DataFrame.loc()` method will raise a KeyError, if it can't found a row with the key, while I want it give me the location of the
   first row whose index value is greater or equals the seeking key
   value.

What is the correct method I should use?

Answer (score 0):

you could consider replacing the date index with an integer index, while still preserving the date column. than you can query your df either with pandas.df.where for the [] approach, like this

```
import pandas as pd

# generate sample data w/ date index
dates = pd.to_datetime(
    ['01-01-1990', '01-02-1990', '01-03-1990'],
    format='%m-%d-%Y'
)
values = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(dates, values), columns=['date', 'value'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# replace date index w/ integer index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# define seeking key
seeking_key = pd.to_datetime('01-02-1990', format='%m-%d-%Y')

# find first index where date >= seeking key
first_index_matching = df[df.date >= seeking_key].index[0]

# query df with first index
print(df.iloc[first_index_matching])
```

output:

```
date     1990-01-02 00:00:00
value                      2
Name: 1, dtype: object
```